# Where are the color themes for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am aware of the Color Themes for Visual Studio, however that only has a few color themes. Is there a marketplace for custom color themes that can be downloaded and imported similar to VS Code? Top name color themes found in VS Code like Materialize are and Atom OneDark are noticeably missing. The market for VS code color themes is booming while I can't find anything outside of the aforementioned Color pack

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a marketplace for custom color themes that can be downloaded and imported similar to VS Code?

There is not a marketplace.  However, there is an extension, that allows you to import supported user themes and create your own themes.

- [Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor)
- [Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2019ColorThemeEditor)

Comment: @Biswapriyo - The themes you linked to only support Visual Studio Code.  So your correction isn't applicable to my answer.